# String to Integer Conversion

Tags: c++

Program 1: Program 1 takes a line of input from the console and divides the input string into sub strings separated by space and then converts into integer value.

```
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h> 

    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    { 
    char *input;
    cin.getline(input,100);

    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    while (token != NULL) 
    {
    cout << token << '\n';
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Program 2:

```
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h> 

    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    { 
    char *input;
    cin.getline(input,100);
    int a[7];
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    while (token != NULL) 
    {
    cout << token << '\n';
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Program 1 works fine but programs does not work. The only difference between two program is that, an additional array a[7] variable. How does this variable leads to crashing of program 2.

Comment: Technically, *none* of your programs works fine. Read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

Because undefined behaviour.

You never allocate memory for `input`, so using it with `getline` is undefined behaviour.

It looks like you just want to read in some text and print it out, split on whitespace. You could just use `std::string` and `operator>>` on `std::cin` for this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you get an undefined behavior because you didn't allocate memory for `input`.

You could fix the problem by declaring a `char` array or by doing things in a more "C++ way". Here's an example:

[[run it online](https://ideone.com/o66V8N)]

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> a;

    cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers: ";

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              std::back_inserter(a));

    cout << "You've entered: ";     
    for (auto& num : a)
    {
        cout << num << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you still want to limit the input till `100` ([i.e. `'d'`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)), you can `getline()` from `cin` to a `std::string` that you use to initialize a `std::istringstream iss` for instance. Then the `std::copy()` code is the same, just replace `cin` with `iss`.

```
// #include <sstream>
std::string input;
cin.getline(input, 100);
std::istringstream iss(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory for `input` to point to, and calling `getline` with an uninitialized pointer is *undefined behavior*.

That means that anything can happen, including your program working as you expected, or not working as expected. Adding the `int a[7]` just changed the memory layout of your program and consequently the behavior of the undefined behavior.

To fix it, you could simply make `input` a static array of the desired length:

```
char input[100];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion. It worked :) :)